# Groovy script выдает ошибку при нахождении символа переноса строки

Tags: groovy

Я использую GroovyShell для выполнения скрипта groovy в java.

Мой скрипт:

```
if ( !Переменная1.equals(Переменная2) ) {
return "Переменная1 = Переменная2";
};

return "Переменная2 = Переменная3
Переменная1 = Переменная3"
```

Я рассчитываю что при выполнении скрипта будет возвращена строка 1:

```
"Переменная1 = Переменная2"
```

или строка 2:

```
return "Переменная2 = Переменная3
Переменная1 = Переменная3"
```

но вместо этого бросается ошибка MultipleCompilationErrorException[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка? Я плохо разбираюсь в groovy, может я что-то принципиально делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том,  что в Groovy для многострочных строк нужно использовать """ или '''